# rxjs - Is it necessary to kill cold stream?

Tags: javascript, stream, rxjs, rxjs5

1. **If subscribe isn't exist, the stream does not work?**
2. **Is it necessary to kill subscribe in cold stream?** For example: operator `.take(1)` or `.first()` or common `.unsubscribe`, so other.

**or may is it necessary to kill himself stream?** `.complete()`
Or does not it affect performance in the future?

A simple example: **Create 100 cold stream**

```
    function test() {
       let obs = Rx.Observable.create(observer => observer.next(Date.now()));       
       obs.subscribe(v => console.log("1st subscriber: " + v));
       obs.subscribe(v => console.log("2nd subscriber: " + v));
     }     
     for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++){
       test();
     }
```

Comment: 1) Yes. 2) It depends upon whether the cold observable completes or errors - e.g. `interval` is cold, but it does not complete, so unsubscription (or `take`/`first`, etc.) is required.

Comment: @cartant - is unsubscribe need, if i use for example angular HttpClient -> `this.http.get().first().subscribe()` or not `this.http.get().subscribe()`?

Comment: @sergamers HttpClient completes, so you don't need to unsubscribe.

Answer (score 0):

Cold streams are just functions not being executed. So creating them will alloc memory but not incur any further performance issues.